# How to disable jumping to warning location after compile in vim-latex?

Tags: vim, latex

After compilation, vim-latex opens a quickfix buffer, lists errors and warnings, and jumps to the first error or warning in the list. How do I make it not jump for warnings? or better yet, for certain warnings?

If this is not possible, is there some shortcut for returning the cursor back to its position before the jump?

NOTE: Ignoring warnings via `let g:TexIgnoredWarnings = ...` is not adequate since I do want to see the warnings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're compiling via Vim-Latex's \ll command as I do, then adding the following option in either your vimrc or the ftplugin tex.vim should solve your problem:

`let g:Tex_GotoError=0`

This will leave your cursor where it was, but still populate the QuickFix window with warnings and errors. The documentation (linked below) says that it defaults to on, so switching it off should accomplish what you want.

http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#Tex_GotoError

Comment: I think it should be let and not set

Comment: Oops. You're correct. That's what I get for typing and not thinking.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are compiling LaTeX with the `:make` command. The [help for that command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3amake_makeprg) gives a list detailing  exactly what the command does, including:

> 1. If `[!]` is not given the first error is jumped to.

If you trigger your compilation with `:make!` or the abbreviation `:mak!` instead of `:make`, then the cursor will not jump.

---

vim also saves a list of places your cursor has been recently. You can jump back to your previous location with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, and then jump forward again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> Use `:help jump-motions` to see more about this feature.